# Why this Angular script is unable to retrieve JSON generated by Laravel 4?

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, laravel

AngularJS

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '//www.ign-design.net/users'
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.user.username = data.name;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

Laravel

```
Route::get('users', function() 
{
    return Response::json(array('name' => 'Anil', 'yas' => 25));
});
```

The problem is, the script works fine when I add `//echo.jsontest.com/name/Anil/yas/25` as the `$http URL`. However, then I add `//www.ign-design.net/users` (which is being generated by Laravel using the code above), it doesn't work. It goes to `.error` and `console.log` outputs: `""`

I don't know what's wrong. Why my Laravel's `Response::json()` doesn't satisfy AngularJS like jsontest.com website? Spent like 2 hours trying to figure it out - no luck.

Ps. Probably a header issue - but I've also tried to output JSON data using plain PHP and setting headers myself. Didn't work either.

Comment: inspect the request itself in network tab of a browser console and see what it's status is, if url is what you expect, if data being returned etc

Comment: also you are using absolute path but with no `http://`  try adding that

Comment: @charlietfl I did. Adding http:// doesn't fix it, and for the past 2 hours I've been trying to see the differences between their response headers and my response headers. No luck, that's why I asked it on SO.

Comment: so what does console tell you about request? Status and response data

Comment: @charlietfl Both similar. Correct headers, correct content type but my response isn't considered as a JSON response from what I see. You can open your dev tools and make a request to both addresses I've posted above and see the whole thing yourself. :)

Comment: oh...is a cross domain problem, are you working on one domain and calling anohter?....`same origin policy` ...need to make it jsonp then at output . Didn't occur to me since you said your issue was with server routing and therefore you controlle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're running into a cross-domain problem. Either move your angular code to the same domain, or make your Laravel code understand how to respond to cross-domain calls.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS for more details.